# Reading pdf files faster with tika Python 3

Tags: python, apache-tika

I am trying to read and find data from pdf files with tika. I have several libreoffice and pdf files with same name but different extension.
First with this straight forward code:

```
from tika import parser
import os
from timeit import default_timer as timer

files_to_search = []
times = []
dir_list = os.listdir(r'\\LS-WVLEF8\backup\laskut\secun')
for file_name in dir_list:
    if file_name.find('nterme')>0 and file_name.find('pdf')>0:
        files_to_search.append(file_name)
for a in range(20):
    tic = timer()
    path_and_name=""
    for item in files_to_search:
        path_and_name = r'\\LS-WVLEF8\backup\laskut\secun'+'\\'+item
        try:
            file_data = parser.from_file(path_and_name)
            text = file_data['content']
            text = text.strip()
            if text.find('835528')>1:
                print('found '+item)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception')
            print(e)
            while 1:
                pass
    tac = timer()
    times.append(tac-tic)
    print('single time ',tac-tic)
    with open('single.txt', 'a') as the_file:
        the_file.write(str(tac-tic)+'\n')
average = sum(times)/20
max = times.index(max(times))
with open('single.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    the_file.write('average = '+str(average)+'\n')
    the_file.write('max = '+str(max)+'\n')
```

It works slowly. I get average average = 1.732

Then with this. With multiprocessing.

```
from tika import tika, parser
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
from timeit import default_timer as timer
def tika_parser(files_to_search):
    try:
        data = parser.from_file(r'\\LS-WVLEF8\backup\laskut\secun\\'+files_to_search)
        text = data['content']
        text = text.strip()
        if text.find('835528')>1:
            print('found ' + files_to_search)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception')
        print(e)
        while 1:
            pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    files_to_search = []
    times = []
    dir_list = os.listdir(r'\\LS-WVLEF8\backup\laskut\secun')
    for file_name in dir_list:
        if file_name.find('nterme')>0 and file_name.find('pdf')>0:
            files_to_search.append(file_name)
    for a in range(20):
        tic = timer()
        pool = Pool()
        pool.map(tika_parser, files_to_search)
        pool.close()
        tac = timer()
        times.append(tac-tic)
        print('multi time ',tac-tic)
        with open('multi.txt', 'a') as the_file:
            the_file.write(str(tac-tic)+'\n')
    average = sum(times)/20
    max = times.index(max(times))
    with open('multi.txt', 'a') as the_file:
        the_file.write('average = '+str(average)+'\n')
        the_file.write('max = '+str(max)+'\n')
```

This is a bit faster. I get average = 1.320

Is there a way to do this faster with tika? Or should I look for PyPDF2 or something else?